# How to query CloudKit for recordID IN [CKRecordID]

Tags: ios, nspredicate, cloudkit, ckquery, ckrecord

My predicate wants to exclude some records that are already downloaded and available in a [CKRecordID]. Now I can query 1 CKRecordID[0], but not the [CKRecordID] array. How can I query the array?

```
let excludeIDs: [CKRecordID]
```

This works:

```
let pred1 = NSPredicate(format: "NOT(recordID = %@)", excludeIDs[0])
```

But this doesn't:

```
let pred1 = NSPredicate(format: "NOT(recordID IN %@)", excludeIDs)
```

ERROR:
loadImageCompareRecordIDsAndEndDateThatHaveNotEnded Error: Invalid predicate: Invalid predicate: Array members must conform to CKRecordValue: (
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    ""
) (CKRecordID)

The other general parts of the code:

```
    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: MyRecordTypes.ImageCompare, predicate: pred1)
    query.sortDescriptors = [sort]
    let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
    operation.desiredKeys = ["endDate"]
    operation.resultsLimit = 50
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [CKReference] and not [CKRecordID] solved it.

Comment: Thanks, strange CKRecordID works for single comparisons

Comment: @SamBallantyne Just convert your record ID's to CKReferences like             let refs = myRecords.map({ CKReference(recordID: $0.record.recordID, action: .None) })

Answer (score 1):

To be explicit (because it took me hours to get this right)...

```
let refs = excludeIDs.map { CKRecord.Reference(recordID: $0.recordID, action: .none) }
let pred1 = NSPredicate(format: "NOT(recordID IN %@)", refs)
```